# I am trying to allocate dynamic memory to element of structure and getting segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate dynamic memory to element of array but i am getting segmentation fault 
This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Octstr
{
      unsigned char *data;
      long len;
      long size;
      int immutable;
};
int main()
{
    struct Octstr *obj;
    obj->data = (char*)malloc(16);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate memory for the `struct` itself: `obj` is uninitialised.

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

Either `malloc` some memory for it or use automatic storage duration:

```
struct Octstr obj;
obj.data = (char*)malloc(16);
```

Finally, don't forget to balance your `malloc` calls with calls to `free`. (Also it's unnecessary to cast the return pointer of `malloc` in C, and do check the return pointer value to check if the allocation was successful).

Comment: And don't forget the calls to `free` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`struct Octstr *obj;` is an uninitialized variable, it stores an unspecified address, and therefore points to an unspecified location.

Dereferencing it by trying to access a member is undefined behavior, which in your case results in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all your pointers by NULL.And make sure you free it after usage of your pointer at the end of your code.